# Assign array without element by element copy?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a function which creates an array, of say, size `5`.

Is it possible for the function to accept a pointer (*or maybe it needs a pointer to a pointer?*) and then point said pointer at an array, so that when the callee then looks at the pointer, it can see all values of the array.

Something along the lines of this (except this will not work):

```
 #define LENGTH 5
 void assignArray(int *pointer)
 {
       int arr[LENGTH] = {0,1,2,3,4};

       // Point the pointer at the array, without manually copying each element
       pointer = arr;
 }

 void main()
 {
       int *pointer;
       pointer = malloc(sizeof(int) * LENGTH);
       assignArray(pointer);

       int i;
       for (i = 0 ; i < LENGTH ; i++) printf("%d\n", pointer[i]);
 }
```

Comment: Change `pointer = arr` to `memcpy(pointer,arr,sizeof(arr))`. You **could** pass a pointer to pointer and then "Point the pointer at the array, without manually copying each element" as you say. But since the array is local, once you're out of the function, your pointer will point to memory that you should not attempt to access (as you don't know what's in there and who else might be using it).

Comment: If you pass the pointer using a pointer (i.e. a pointer to the pointer), then you can make it point to the array. However that won't work as the array goes out of scope once the function returns, leaving you with a stray pointer and probable [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 2):

> *C assign array without element by element copy*

In `C`, arrays (compile-time allocated) cannot be *assigned*. You need to copy the elements from one array to another.

To avoid element-by-element copy, you can copy the whole array all at a time using library function.

I'm not very sure what you want to ask here, but it seems, you need to do [`memcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy) to achieve your goal.

If you have a secondary array `arr` to *copy from*, you can write

```
 memcpy( pointer, arr, ( (sizeof arr[0]) * LENGTH ));
```

Comment: `memcpy` is what OP needs to get the job done, but is also important to explain why OP should not use 'pointer to a pointer' in this situation, as explained by @barak manos

Comment: @JonatanGoebel that depends. a `static` array would handle the situation just fine. Let's not _generalize_ the situation. :-)

Comment: For the specific question and example, a static array would avoid undefined behavior, but  would not make it to be right, only a very bad design choice.

Comment: @JonatanGoebel it's personal choice, though I agree with you in this case. Please see [Matt's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30166457/2173917) also.

Answer (score 1):

The code to do what you are describing might look like:

```
#define LENGTH 5
void assignArray(int **pp)
{
   static int arr[LENGTH] = {0,1,2,3,4};

   // Point the pointer at the array, without manually copying each element
   *pp = arr;
}

int main()
{
    int *pointer;
    assignArray(&pointer);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < LENGTH ; i++) 
        printf("%d\n", pointer[i]);
}
```

Note that one does not simply point `*pp` at a non-static local variable `arr`. That is because `int arr[] = ....` would go out of scope when `assignArray` returns.

If you want each call to `assignArray` to "return" a different array then of course you will have to allocate space and use `memcpy` each time you want to make a copy of the original array.

Answer (score 0):

`int arr[LENGTH] = {0,1,2,3,4};` will be *stack allocated*, so attempting to return the pointer to any of its elements will give you undefined behaviour as the whole thing will be out of scope when the function returns.

If you want to change what a pointer is pointing to then use 2 levels of indirection `**` (i.e. pass a pointer to a pointer). You'll need to allocate the array `arr` on the *heap* using `malloc` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to do it, it is not possible due to the fact that your local `arr` is saved to the stack and is cleaned up after the function `assignArry` finished. As already mentioned you need to `memcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer will have two parts:

As mentioned in other answers, this is now how you're supposed to do it. A common construct in similar code is:

```
void assignArray(int *dest, size_t size)
{
       int i;

       // initialize with some data
       for (i=0; i<size; i++)
               dest[i] = i;
}
```

This way you're not wasting space and time with an intermediate buffer.

---

Second part of this answer is about wrapping arrays in a struct. It's a silly trick, that in a way achieves exactly what you asked, and also something that you probably don't want because of extra data copying.

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LENGTH 5
struct foo { int arr[LENGTH]; };

struct foo assignArray()
{
        struct foo bar = { .arr = {0,1,2,3,4} };

        /* return the array wrapper in struct on stack */
        return bar;
}

int main()
{
        struct foo *pointer;
        pointer = malloc(sizeof(*pointer));
        *pointer = assignArray(); /* this will copy the data, not adjust pointer location */

        int i;
        for (i = 0 ; i < LENGTH ; i++) printf("%d\n", pointer->arr[i]);

        return 0;
}
```